# C++ ¿Cómo ordenar un map según su Key?

Tags: c++, map, diccionarios

Cómo se puede ordenar un map alfabéticamente cuyas Keys son strings?
Necesito crear un inventario de productos (string) junto con el contenido de cada producto, un int. Se me pide que cree una función que escriba todos los productos que hay en el almacén junto con su cantidad EN ORDEN ALFABÉTICO de producto. Teniendo en cuenta que los productos se irán añadiendo en el map de forma aleatoria, sin ningún orden. ¿Es posible ordenarlos cuando ya tengo un map con varios productos? O debería insertar cada producto de manera ordenada desde un principio? Cualquier consejo se agradece!
Os dejo aquí el pre y el post junto con la descripción de la función:

Para cada producto del sistema se escribe su identificador y la cantidad total en el almacen, ordenado por identificador de producto.
  \pre *cierto*
  \post  Listado de productos y cantidad de cada producto ordenados por 
         identificador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En C++ tienes la clase `std::map` que implementa un contenedor en el que las cosas están ordenadas por una clave dada... en tu caso sería el string:

```
class Producto
{
  std::string nombre;

public:

  std::string Nombre()
  { return nombre; }

  void SetNombre(std::string nombre)
  { this->nombre = nombre; }
};

std::map<std::string,Producto> mapa;
```

Lo malo de este mecanismo es que posiblemente te obligue a duplicar el identificador del producto (en el propio producto y en el mapa):

```
Producto p;
p.SetNombre("abc");

mapa.insert(std::make_pair(p.Nombre(),p));
```

Para salvar esta situación puedes optar por usar un contenedor de tipo `set`. La mayor diferencia entre `set` y `map` es que el primero no tiene un índice... aunque los datos siguen estando ordenados:

```
std::set<Producto> contenedor;

contenedor.insert(p);
```

Eso sí, al probar el código anterior verás que aparece un error durante la compilación. Esto es debido a que `set` no sabe cómo se debe ordenar la colección de elementos. Este *inconveniente* lo puedes salvar de varias formas:

1. Implementas el operador `<` para la clase producto:

   ```
   bool operator<(Producto const& p1, Producto const& p2)
   {
     return p1.nombre < p2.nombre;
   }
   ```
2. Le proporcionas al `set` una función de comparación:

   ```
   bool OrdenaProductos(Producto const& p1, Producto const& p2)
   {
     return p1.nombre < p2.nombre;
   }

   std::set<Producto,OrdenaProductos> contenedor;
   ```

### Bonus

Al mapa también es posible indicarle cómo debe ordenar los elementos de la misma forma que el `set`. En el caso de `map`, al ordenar por la clave (que recordemos que para este caso concreto es un `std::string`), por defecto ordenará de forma alfabética sin decirle nada ya que el operador *menor que* ya viene implementado en la librería `string`.

Si quieres que el mapa tenga ordene de forma diferente los productos tendrás que proporcionar una función específica (por ejemplo si quieres que la ordenación sea insensible a las mayúsculas o si quieres ignore los acentos):

```
std::map<std::string,Producto,OrdenarProductos> mapa;
```